# datatables not working with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, datatables

I have a datatable with dynamic content that is been taken from an mysql database.
If I have no records, the table shows correctly with the search bar ETC.
But once I add the data, it removes the search bat, the pagination and the sorting options in the thead.

This is my code:

In the header:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://datatables.net/examples/resources/demo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userstable').DataTable( {
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Hebrew.json"
        }
    } );
} );

    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/datatables.css">
```

In the body:

```
    <table id="userstable" class="table display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
                <th class="text-center">תמונה</th>
                <th class="text-center">שם פרטי</th>
                <th class="text-center">שם משפחה</th>
                <th class="text-center">שם משתמש</th>
                <th class="text-center">דוא"ל</th>
                <th class="text-center">קבוצה</th>
                <th class="text-center">פעיל</th>
                <th class="text-center">נוצר ב</th>
                <th class="text-center">עריכה</th>
                <th class="text-center">מחיקה</th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>

<?php

                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                            echo "<tr>
                            <td class='text-center'>" . $row['avatar'] . "</td>
                            <td class='text-center'>" . $row['firstName'] . "</td>
                            <td class='text-center'>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td>
                            <td class='text-center'>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
                            <td class='text-center'>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
                            <td class='text-center'>" . $row['userGroup'] . "</td>
                            <td class='text-center'>" . $row['active'] . "</td>
                            <td class='text-center'>" . $row['userGroup'] . "</td>
                            <td class='text-center'><a href='edituser.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' type='button' class='btn btn-info'>עריכה</td>
                            <td class='text-center'><a href='deleteuser.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>מחיקה</td>
                            <tr>";

                            }  

?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is a short video that shows the problem:

http://recordit.co/sfuMTXW7Be

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...
I did not close the a tags in the 2 last td's of the table...